# Onesignal c# web_buttons

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, onesignal

I am trying to send a notification from my backend with the following code:

```
var obj = new
            {
                app_id = new Guid(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["oneSignalAppid"]),
                contents = new { en = "English Message"},
                headings = new { en = "English heading" },
                chrome_web_image = https://pixabay.com/static/img/no_hotlinking.png",
                 web_buttons = @"[
                                {
                                    'id': 'like-button',
                                    'text': 'Like',
                                    'icon': 'http://i.imgur.com/N8SN8ZS.png',
                                    'url': 'https://yoursite.com'},
                                {
                                    'id': 'read-more-button',
                                    'text': 'Read more',
                                    'icon': 'http://i.imgur.com/MIxJp1L.png',
                                    'url': 'https://yoursite.com'
                                            }]",
                included_segments = new string[] { "All" }
            };
```

either i  get a 400 response or i get my notification without the buttons.

How do i set the web_buttons properly?

Answer (score 1):

the solution is to serialize the array object using anonymous array of anonymous types:

```
  web_buttons = new[] {

                   new {id="id-1", text= buttonText, url="http://yourDomain.com" },

                }
```

...